# Pass multiple parameters, choose one that's been passed in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Calling my method:

```
    fpt.CouttsPositionSection.AssetClassAssets.Add(dataGenerator.GenerateFPTAssetClassAsset(fpt,*different parameter*));
```

My method:

```
    public FPTAssetClassAsset GenerateFPTAssetClassAsset(FPT fpt, *4 parameters, with different variable names*)
    {
        FPTStaticDataAssetClassAssetlist = db.FPTStaticDataRatedFinancialAssetBase.OfType<FPTStaticDataAssetClassAsset>().Where(e => e.FORATExcelId == 1).ToList();
        var fptdocassets = fpt.CouttsPositionSection.AssetClassAssets.Select(e => e.StaticDataAssetClassAsset).ToList();
        var listTemp = FPTStaticDataAssetClassAssetlist.Where(i => !fptdocassets.Contains(i)).ToList();
        FPTAssetClassAsset a = new FPTAssetClassAsset();
        a.StaticDataAssetClassAsset = listTemp[random.Next(0, listTemp.Count())];
        a.Currency = a.StaticDataAssetClassAsset.Currency;
        a.Description = a.StaticDataAssetClassAsset.Name + " Descr";
        a.Holdings.Add(GenerateFPTRatedFinancialAssetHolding());
        FillCommonRateFinancialAssetData(a, fpt);
        fpt.UpdateXrates(a.StaticDataAssetClassAsset.CurrencyId);
        return a;
    }
```

When i run the method it will be called 4 times with 4 different parameters. If i set 4 optional parameters that's fine, however they all have different variable names. Below the variable name will go between the stars, but i have 4 so is there any way of having the variable change its value or name?

```
var fptdocassets = fpt.*variable of parameter passed*.AssetClassAssets
```

Comment: Are your four different parameters of different `Types`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing in a string instead, and using the following method to return the object that it matched.

```
    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
```